# Best Option for Compatibility of "Linux Journaling File System" and "Volume Manager" with Microsoft Azure VMs

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, lvm, azure-vm, journalling

I'm in the process of setting up a Ubuntu Desktop VM on a bare metal server using VMware vSphere.
Once the development process is complete, I plan to transfer the VM to Microsoft Azure VM infrastructure for production using Veeam Backup & Replication.
However, I'm uncertain about the best choice for the "Linux Journaling File System" and "Volume Manager" during the VM installation on VMware vSphere, considering compatibility with Azure VMs and the flexibility to change the disk size (expanding and shrinking) when necessary.

These are the options I have for "Journaling File System" and "Volume Manager" during the Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.2 LTS installation:

If I choose "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu" during the installation process (Installation type window):

```
1.1. ext4 (By choosing "None" on the Advanced Features window)
1.2. ext4 + LVM (By choosing "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation" on the Advanced Features window)
1.3. ZFS (By choosing "Erase disk and use ZFS" on the Advanced Features window)
```

If I choose "Something else" during the installation process (Installation type window), I will have multiple options such as:

```
2.1. NTFS
2.2. ext4
2.3. btrfs
2.4. JFS
2.5. XFS
```

**I want to make an informed decision to avoid encountering the same problem I faced in a previous experience, which is describe below.**

---

- Information about one of my previous experiences related to this
  matter raised the above question in my mind:

I had a negative experience with a previous installation using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.5 LTS, where I encountered issues when attempting to expand the OS disk. The configuration of that installation was as follows:

- Journaling File System: ext4
- Volume Manager: LVM (By choosing "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation" on the Advanced Features window during installation)
- OS Version: Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.5 LTS
- Linux VM Main Host: VMware vSphere
- Transferred to Azure using: Veeam Backup & Replication

After [increasing the OS disk size from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk#resize-a-managed-disk-in-the-azure-portal), my Ubuntu desktop became stuck on the boot screen and continuously displayed the message "Press Ctrl+C to cancel all filesystem checks in progress." This message persisted even after an extended period of time (I observed this through boot diagnostics, which provided a screenshot of the OS window). Despite numerous email exchanges and remote sessions with support engineers, the problem remained unresolved. It seems that the combination of LVM volume manager and having a swap partition on the OS disk complicated the resolution process.

Based on Azure documentation, I found the following recommendations:
[Create and upload an Ubuntu Linux VHD in Azure - Azure Virtual Machines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu#prerequisites)

1. When installing the Linux system it's recommended that you use
   standard partitions rather than LVM (often the default for many
   installations). This will avoid LVM name conflicts with cloned VMs,
   particularly if an OS disk ever needs to be attached to another VM
   for troubleshooting.
2. Don't configure a swap partition or swap file on the OS disk.

---

I would greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions regarding the choice of "Linux Journaling File System" and "Volume Manager" for my Ubuntu Desktop VM, considering the compatibility and flexibility requirements with Azure VMs.

Thank you all in advance for your assistance!